# Sending Authorization header on blackberry using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, blackberry

I have been trying to set Authorization header for my ajax call. It works great in all browsers except on Blackberry 4.6

Has anyone managed to make this work? Its particaly frustrating as the [doc](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11849/XMLHttpRequest_573779_11.jsp#XMLHttpRequest_setRequestHeader_620056_11) mentions several headers that are not allowed, but not this one!

I am trying to do this with a website, not webworks.

The code is along these lines

```
$.ajax({
     url: path,
     headers: {
         Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
     },
     ...
});
```

Comment: please share the ajax call code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the blackberry prior to OS6 won't send this header. The only option seems to be to use another non-standard header or send the auth details in a POST body or similar. Either way some support on the server side is needed.